# Wire shield when using connector for strain gauge sensor

Tags: analog, strain-gage, shield

I have made strain gauge sensor with 1 strain gauge. Thet gauge is in "bottom" part of Wheatstone brigde (one strain gauge terminal is signal, second is connected to ground).

I'm using Sommer CICADA SO-D14 200-0451 cable. It's shield drain wre is connected to GND in the same spot at PCB as strain gauge wire.

Right now I'm not using any connector, but I'd like to make sensor instalation easier.

Now it looks like that:
[image: Now]

Dark green - PCB with yellow solder points
Grey - sensor - it's just a piece of aluminium with strain gauge bonded to it. Shield drain wire is not connected to it.
Red - one strain gauge terminal (signal)
Blue - second strain gauge terminal (GND)
Green - Shield drain wire.

As I'd like to use connector I found 2 options:
1. Use 2-pin connector, shield drain wire connected to gnd terminal of strain gauge at sensor side of connector, but on pcb side of connector it will be connected only to gnd at pcb. I'll use that connector close to pcb - then It will be similar situation to one which is right now.

[image: Way 1]

2. Use of 3 pin connector with one pin just for shield drain wire.

[image: Way2]

Will 2nd way a lot better than 1?

Connecting shield drain wire to GND at sensor side of connector is not possible (only ground point is at pcb).

Maybe there are other options?

Comment: show what is inside the GREY boxes

Comment: I'm sorry for not telling that. Grey is just a piece of aluminium with strain gauge bonded to it. Shield drain wire is not connected to anything at this side